# ATmega stopped working after changing CKDIV8 fuse

Tags: atmel, atmel-studio, fuse-bits, atmega32u4

I have ATmega32U4. I connected it via SPI programmer and in Atmel Studio I have read their signature properly. It was working. Then I cleared and programmed CKDIV8 fuse. Clock was set to internal RC. After that the device stopped responding. No other fuse i have changed. Since that time it don´t respond to any SPI command and also it does not respond to any JTAG command.

Do you know what happened to it and how to fix it?

Comment: If you have enabled clock division with a large ratio, you may need a very slow clock for ISP programming, something that not all improvised solutions (like arduinos acting as ISP adapters) may honor.  If you have selected an external clock source, you may need to inject a clock or provide a crystal.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that CKDIV8 fuse will speed up it 8 times but it really slow down it 8 times.

Comment: But I have a new one problem. I can read device signature but all fuses (and lock bits) persists at state 0x00 and programing them does not change nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I was bitten once by changing the clock fuses where it was not operating fast enough for the setting I was using on the programmer. The programmer would fail to communicate with the device.

The clock for the programmer must be no faster than 1/4 of the CPU clock.

I'm using Avrdude and there is a command argument to set the clocking speed.

For example:

avrdude -v -p attiny84 -c avrisp2 -U flash:w:main.hex:i -B 128

The -B argument specifies the clock period in microseconds.

This is assuming, of course, that you haven't accidentally programmed one of the other fuses that disables the ISP interface.

In that case a HV programmer may be the only solution. There are some simple designs on the web (can't find them at the moment) using an Arduino and a few other components to 'unbrick' mis-programmed devices. They can easily be built in can hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need a High Voltage (12V) Programmer to clear the fuses back to usable settings.